# Как связать 1 домен и 2 сервера?

Tags: веб-сервер, dns, поддомены

Есть домен http://example.com и 2 сервера (1 хостинг на рег.ру, 2 VPS с белым IP).
Как сделать, чтобы при обращении к  http://**first**.example.com шло на обращение на сервер 1, а при обращении к http://**second**.example.com

Comment: Добавить А-записи

| Type | Domain name         | IP address   |
|:----:|:-------------------:|:------------:|
| A    | first.example.com.  | 37.137.237.7 |
| A    | second.example.com. | 47.147.247.7 |

Comment: На подобные вопросы обычно поддержка хостинга отвечает, или регистратора домен.

Comment: Спасибо.
Тех суппорт по 12 часов отвечает иногда ))) тут быстрее